# Execute curl command in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, curl, urllib

I am executing a curl command on windows which runs fine & return a json response.Below is the curl command.

`curl -X GET -u user_name:password -k "https://dev-instance.company-domain.com/rest/v1/audit/export?offset=6&limit=2"`

I want execute the same using python 3. I used urllib, urllib2 library etc.

The Python code snippets available online, are for Python 2.x. and not working in Python 3.x. Please help me on using the appropriate Python library.

Regards,

Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is a superbly documented library one can use to make HTTP requests.

I believe your curl line would translate to:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://dev-instance.company-domain.com/rest/v1/audit/export?offset=6&limit=2', auth=('user', 'pass')).json()
```

Comment: @nnt0  
I tried the code snippet suggested by you. But it gives me following error.
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "No module named 'requests'",
  "errorType": "ModuleNotFoundError",

It seems like there is difference in requests library in Python 2.x & 3.x. I am looking for some working code for Python 3.6